# Using a Dynamic SQL in the CURSOR's FOR LOOP

Tags: loops, for-loop, dynamic, cursor, db2

After hours of searching, I can't seem to find the solution to this simple thing!

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE P()
  LANGUAGE SQL
  BEGIN ATOMIC
    DECLARE fullname CHAR(40);

    FOR v AS cur1 CURSOR FOR 
                SELECT firstnme, midinit, lastname FROM employee
    DO 
      SET fullname = v.lastname || ',' || v.firstnme 
                     ||' ' || v.midinit;
      INSERT INTO tnames VALUES (fullname);
    END FOR;
  END
```

The above block of DB2 stored procedure uses a FOR loop for a STATIC SQL, I have tried replacing the SQL with a Dynamic SQL variable but it does not work. Any help would be great.

I know we can use OPEN..FETCH..LOOP block to do the same, but my requirement is to use a FOR Loop for this.

Many thanks :)
Faisal.

Comment: You have a typo in `firstnme`, it should be `firstname`.

Comment: @Barmar in the example, `firstnme` is a column name in table `employee`.  This code is in the Knowledge Centers for DB2/i & DB2/LUW. The example is a bit different for DB2/z.

Comment: Why is the `a` missing? Are column names in DB2 limited to 8 characters?

Comment: No, we can use long names, but that doesn't mean you have to use complete English spelling for names. You can abbreviate or spell however you wish, when defining the table.

Comment: Guys, please ignore the typo, it happened while typing the code block here. But this is just an example only for your reference, not my actual code of course :) The question was very simple, can a FOR Cursor loop be used with a dynamic SQL or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOR is a static, compiled statement that does not allow a prepared statement name to be used in place of the SELECT statement.

You may want to review your interpretation of the requirements, or think outside the box to approach this from an entirely new angle.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to hear :) Thank you for confirming that a FOR cursor loop is a static statement and does not allow prepared / dynamic SQL strings.

Comment: Unless there is a compelling reason, it is generally better to use SQL statements that will process all applicable rows at once (sometimes called set-at-a-time) rather than loop through row-at-a-time. There are occasionally  times where row-at-a-time can simplify working with complex relationships between rows, but generally, I would suggest trying to find ways to do express it with set-at-a-time first, if you can, before evaluating which is better.  But where a loop makes your code easier for the next person to understand, that is a fair factor to consider.

Comment: Hi Warren, this is a wise suggestion indeed, having few years of experience I can understand and prefer bulk insert, update and delete vs a cursor based operation. But this particular requirement go through a few table updates and a complex logic that decides what to do. That is why it was decided to do this way :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single `INSERT ... SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO tnames
SELECT lastname || ',' || firstnme ||' ' || midinit
FROM employee;
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar! But again this is not what I asked in the original post :)